# Having problems fitting a table to a Column in LaTeX

Tags: latex, overleaf

I have my template set that subsections go into 2 columns, however when I try and insert a table, it does not compile instead being left blank. I think the reason is that the table is too wide/not being fitted.

Here is my LaTeX

```
\subsection{On examination}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
{\ul \textbf{Symptom}}    & {\ul \textbf{Patient}}     & {\ul \textbf{Normal}} \\ \hline
\textit{Temperature}      & 36.7C                      & 36-36.8               \\ \hline
\textit{BMI}              & 31 kg/m\textasciicircum{}2 & 18.5-24.9             \\ \hline
\textit{Heart Rate}       & 70bpm                      & 60-100bpm             \\ \hline
\textit{Blood Pressure}   & 145/80 mmHg                & \textless{}140/90mmHg \\ \hline
\textit{Respiratory Rate} & 12 breaths/min             & 12-18 breaths/min     \\ \hline
\textit{Misc}             &                            &                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: (off-topic: have a look at the siunitx package to correctly typeset values and units)

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage{soul}` and `\begin{table}[htbp]`?